# Can we change the feature of the widget we use it after creating it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, android-button

my question is: Can we change the feature of the widget we use it after creating it? Here I want to change the size of the text inside my button but I cannot change it because I am using this widget elsewhere and I want the size to stay the same. Is there any way to do this?

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: null,
            style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(const Color.fromARGB(184, 202, 202, 67))),
            child: const boldText("BAŞLA"),
          ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can change properties of a Widget using the setState method or using other state management libraries. If you want to change the initial Text of the button store the String inside a variable and change the value of that variable inside a setState method. See the docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html